# Riemannian metric given in polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, polar-coordinates

the Riemannian metric of the euclidean plane is given in polar coordinates as
\begin{align*}
ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2.
\end{align*}
Consider more generally,
\begin{align*}
ds^2=dr^2+\psi(r)^2d\theta^2,
\end{align*}
where $\psi>0$ is a smooth function.

It seems to me a very natural question to ask what happens if the function $\psi$ changes. Is it possible to 'tell' what kind of Riemannian manifold correspond to such a metric if we choose different functions $\psi$ ( e.g. $\psi^2(r)=r,r^3,r^4,.. etc.)$

For example, if we choose $\psi(x)^2=\sinh(x)^2$ we 'obtain' the hyperbolic plane, i.e. the hyperbolic metric in polar coordinates is equal to the corresponding metric. Do other choices of $\psi$ have some significant meaning, or are there maybe well known examples which can be found in some literature?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential mapping creates a metric of the form

\begin{align*}
ds^2=dr^2+\psi(r,\theta)^2d\theta^2,
\end{align*}

locally in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of any point $p$ on a two-dimensional manifold. Your condition expresses a local symmetry: on a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $p$ the metric is invariant with respect to a translation in the $\theta$ coordinate (we could call it a 'local rotation').

It makes a lot of difference if you want that kind of metric in one point or in every point, and in the latter case if the function $\psi$ has to be the same for every point (it isn't in your examples with $\psi^2(r)=r,r^3\ldots$).

If the same function $\psi(r)$ is valid around every point $p$ then we are in the realm of surfaces of constant curvature; to see this, note that the curvature for a general $\psi(r)$ is given by

$$K=-\frac1{\sqrt G}\frac{\partial^2\sqrt G}{\partial r^2}$$

where $G=1.\psi^2(r)$ is the determinant of the matrix expressing the components of the metric tensor. This shows that the function $\psi(r)$ uniquely determines the curvature at the origin of the coordinate system. If all origins have the same function $\psi(r)$ then all origins have the same scalar curvature.

Thus constant curvature implies $\psi''/\psi$ must be constant. Depending on the sign of the constant (the opposite of the sign of the curvature), the solutions of that differential equation are: first-degree polynomials (your example of a Euclidean plane), a scaled, shifted version of the hyperbolic sine (your example of a hyperbolic sphere) and a scaled, shifted version of the ordinary sine (a sphere). The shift can be eliminated by requiring $\psi(0)=0.$

The sphere of radius $R$ has $\psi(r)=\sin(r/R).$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was assuming that the metric is the same in every point like in the euclidean case. But what do you mean by "it isn't in your examples...". Is it impossible to have a metric with, say $\psi(r)=r$, which holds in every point?

Comment: Slight confusion: I meant $\psi^2(r)=r$ as in your example, but yes, that is impossible. The function $\psi(r)$ fixes the scalar curvature of the manifold at every distance $r$ from the centre. If the same function applies everywhere, then that curvature (as a function of $r$) has to be constant.

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not get it yet. Why does it work in the euclidean case with $\psi(r)^2=r^2$ then? Would you please try to explain it to me?

Comment: I have included an explicit formula for the curvature, showing that $\psi(r)=r$ and $\psi(r)=\sinh r$ solve a specific differential equation that some other examples do not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have understood your argument.